# EDX Course API: Getting EDX course list

Tags: python, api, edx

I am making a project in python/flask. I want to get a list of all the courses of edx. But the API provides the list page by page. I can't figure out how to get the entire list. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using this endpoint
 https://courses.edx.org/api/courses/v1/courses/

As can be seen, there is a `pagination` block in the result:

```
"pagination": {
        "count": 3261,
        "previous": null,
        "num_pages": 327,
        "next": "https://courses.edx.org/api/courses/v1/courses/?page=2"
    },
```

The `next` field in this block will help you fetch the next page of the results. You cannot fetch all the courses in one go.