# Is there a way to search for an edx course using their API?

Tags: python, python-requests, edx

I have an [edX](https://course-catalog-api-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/course_catalog/catalog.html#get-information-about-a-specific-catalog) client ID and secret ID, and I'm able to get the list of all edX online courses, but I want to be able to search through all of the edX courses with a query string like `"robotics"`. (Unlike this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203038/edx-course-api-getting-edx-course-list), I already understand how to get the list of courses, so this is not a duplicate question...) I tried

```
import requests

# I also tried with search_query instead of search
edx_course_search_response = requests.get('https://api.edx.org/catalog/v1/catalogs/'+edx_course_catalog_id+'/courses/'+"?search=robotics", headers=headers)
```

I know the catalog id and headers information is correct because I can get the list of edX courses. Unfortunately, this does not work and instead returns the first 20 online courses in edX's database as usual.

If I can't, I think I'm going to use [whoosh](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EDX Course API: Getting EDX course list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203038/edx-course-api-getting-edx-course-list)

Comment: @dexter I already understand how to get the edX course list like I already said in the question... I need to be able to find a list of courses that match a query string

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

*query* is a response value from this endpoint:  [GET /catalog/v1/catalogs/{id}/](https://course-catalog-api-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/course_catalog/catalog.html#get-information-about-a-specific-catalog). The endpoint for retrieving info about a specific catalog. It is not a user passed parameter. The user parameter is catalog id.

You might use this endpoint: /catalog/v1/catalogs/{id}/courses/

That endpoint, as mentioned in comments has an answer covering pagination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203038/edx-course-api-getting-edx-course-list). You could then filter the returned dataset with python according to your query term. The results array in response values from that endpoint has fields such as short description/long description/title which might be useful to target.